# JAXB Unmarshalling nested tag to root class

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I would like to use JAXB to unmarshall the following XML to Person Class, but just adding `@XmlElement(name = "postcode")` to postcode field in Person class does not work. What am I missing here please?

```
<Person>
    <name>xyz</name>
    <age>123</age>
    <details>
        <phone>123342</phone>
        <postcode>xyz</postcode>
    </details>
</Person>


public Class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String postcode; 

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing subnodes with Jersey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708532/parsing-subnodes-with-jersey)

Comment: This has been resolved with the suggestion here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708532/parsing-subnodes-with-jersey

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that postcode is a child of the details subnode.  You need to create a Details object with phone and postcode as children.  Details would look like

```
public class Details
{
    String phone;
    String postcode;
}
```

And Person would look like:

```
public Class Person 
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Details details;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but I actually wanted to model this in a single domain object. XmlJavaTypeAdapter suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708532/parsing-subnodes-with-jersey helped me resolve this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that was your goal.  Glad you got it sorted out!